# global variable/array unset when hook_field_presave() is being called

Tags: entities

I am trying to pass a global array and work with it in hook_field_presave() but that global array is unset. How do I pass a global array and work with it in presave?

example

```
function find_feed_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
   etc.
   etc.
global $testvar;
$testvar = $array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    );
}

function find_feed_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
   global $testvar;
   dpm ($tesvar);  // result = NULL
   etc.
   etc.
}
```

Comment: From purely PHP point of view what you do makes sense, BUT be aware that not all hook calls happen in the same http request. Specifically creation of a widget and submit handling from said widget *cannot* happen in one call, so there is no way global variables set in one will be visible in the other. So the answer to "how do I pass a global array?" is simply **you don't**. Now, if you would tell us what this array is, logically, what is it's role in your program, we could point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am using simplepie as a function to find RSS feeds. When called upon it will fill in my custom field-names with the nessecary data, like URL/TITLE/Description etc ect. However, the array that simplepie returns contains a lot more info which i need to work with during presave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will never work - global variables only exist in the context of a single page request. Since the form build and presave happen in different requests, you can't use globals in the way you're trying to.

Use a session var instead, that will persist

Comment: Session var is also unset, I have tried that.

Comment: If your session vars aren't persisting then you have a serious problem with your app/server. I doubt it though, you wouldn't be able to login to the site if that were true

Comment: if I set $_session['my_var'] = some array(); in my callback function or during widget creation, it will be gone when function hook_presave() is called.

Comment: Yeah, the global session var is all caps - `$_SESSION`. You're setting the wrong thing

Comment: yes, I used $_SESSION :) trust me, it is unset.

Comment: Well you can guarantee the problem is one of these: 1. Sessions do not work in your PHP installation, 2. You have a rogue custom/contrib module which is emptying session vars (Drupal core does not do this), or 3. You have a typo/other silly error. There isn't any other logic explanation for the position you find yourself in. If you can login to the site, you can rule out number 1 at least

Comment: Or 4., the widget form is cached so your code is not being run every time the form is requested. A dpm in the widget function will tell you that straight away

Comment: Okay, so I stand corrected. I used DPM to print out the $_SESSION, but every time it gave me nada. So I fired up netbeans and debugged each line and kept watching $_SESSIONS, took me a while though, haha :) anyway when DPM is called in hook_presave() for some reason it is not printing out $_SESSIONS completely, in netbeans I see it being active and working. So your answer is correct

Comment: Glad it's working :)

Comment: Took me all morning to figure this out, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The "drupal way" would be to serialize the value you want to keep, and save it with :

```
variable_set('name_of_your_variable', serialize($your_array));
```

Then get the value with :

```
variable_get('name_of_your_variable', 'default_value');
```

But if the variable is user-related, it will obviously not work and you will have to use the sessions, as indicated above.